# Cant read parameters when the controller is inside of a plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I have two Grails 4 websites with its own views, controllers, services, etc. and both projects load a set of shared controllers and views from a plugin.

Grails is able to identify the controllers of the web projects and the plugin. When I perform an action on a gsp of any project, I'm able to debug it's attached controller. The problem is that Im not able to read the parameters of the controllers living inside of the plugin.

This code:

```
    def updateAdress() {
        [....]
        def newAdress = params.adress
        [...] 
    }
```

Throws the following exception:

```
No such property: params for class: my.package.UserController. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: params for class: my.package.UserController
    at my.package.UserController.updateAdress(UserController.groovy:38)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

One of the things that I did to understand what's happening was to copy the controller from the plugin to one of the web projects and debug it on my IDE. The same code worked perfectly and it was interesting to see that apparently Grails is successfully loading its web context on the controllers living in the main projects but not on the controllers coming from the plugin.

This is what I have available when the controller is loaded from the plugin:

[image: Plugin]

While this is what I have available when its loaded from the main web project:

[image: Web]

Comment: Without seeing the project it is hard to say exactly what is wrong but quite likely something is misconfigured in the IDE project.  There are literally thousands of Grails plugins that contain controllers, a completely common practice.

Comment: After checking the issue a million times I played with the project dependencies and seems like I was missing some of them in the plugin.